# How can I introduce my dog to a new home with minimal stress?

Tags: dogs, house-moving

We recently moved from a condo to a full house with a yard and would like some pointers on how best to introduce a dog to the new household, a household which will no doubt have a range of foreign, strange smells.

We have a 2 year old Basset hound male, he is very mild tempered, happy go lucky and submissive.

Also, The next door neighbour's dog is a very vocal and dominant 'guard dog' for the neighbouring yard (fully fenced).

How can we make the transition as stress-free as possible for him?

Comment: PLEASE CLARIFY: Is the 2-year old Basset the dog you are introducing to the home, or is there a second NEW dog that you are introducing to the home?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you arrive take him for a long walk around the new neighbourhood before entering the house with him. when you get back to the new house provide food and water and prepare his new sleeping place with his blanket/pillow that he normally sleeps on.

This will tire him out and the sleeping spot will provide a familiar scent.

If at all possible coordinate with the neighbour to introduce him to his dog, if they hit it off then you just found a potential dog-sitter.

Comment: Thanks for this - we put his bed in the area he normally slept in the condo (living area) and he seems much more relaxed.